# Physical equality test for functions in Caml

Tags: function, ocaml, equality, caml

In Caml, the operator `==` tests the physical equality between two values of a same type. It can be used in particular to compare functions in this way.

One has for instance

```
# print_string == print_string;;
- : bool = true
```

but, surprisingly,

```
# (==) == (==);;
- : bool = false
```

This expression should be evaluated into `true`.

Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: `(==)` does not exist as a closure ready to be, say, passed to a high-order function. Its applications are created directly in inlined form. A closure is allocated each time one is needed, and two such closures are allocated, at different addresses, when you write `(==) == (==)`. If you want similar properties to `print_string`, with current OCaml implementations, give a name to a single closure that you will force yourself to use everywhere: `let phys_equal x y = x == y;;`. This might also be more memory-efficient than allocating closures for an unapplied `(==)` every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of `==` is defined in the [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) module:

> e1 == e2 tests for physical equality of e1 and e2. On mutable types such as references, arrays, byte sequences, records with mutable fields and objects with mutable instance variables, e1 == e2 is true if and only if physical modification of e1 also affects e2. On non-mutable types, the behavior of ( == ) is implementation-dependent; however, it is guaranteed that e1 == e2 implies compare e1 e2 = 0

Since functions aren't mutable, the only guarantee is that if they compare equal with `==` they will also compare equal with `compare`. Since functions aren't guaranteed to be be comparable with `compare`, this essentially means that `==` isn't useful at all for comparing functions.

```
# compare (==) (==);;
Exception: Invalid_argument "equal: functional value".
```

If `==` returns `false` for immutable values, there are no guarantees at all. This means that `==` is free to return `false` at any time for any immutable values. So it's not improper to return `false` in your second example.